# Extract directory path from file path

Tags: awk, sed

I have a requirement for getting part of the string which should be read from end of the string. Like below:

```
a/b/c/d.txt
```

Now I want to get the output as `/a/b/c/` – basically the path of the file. For this, I want the string to be read from the end and where the first `/` appears, it prints till the first text of the string.

Comment: See `dirname` function.

Comment: @aragaer That swallows the last `/`, though.

Comment: Where does the first `/` in `/a/b/c/` come from? The input didn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single variable then how about parameter expansion.
Let's say we have following A variable with your provided value.

```
echo $A
a/b/c/d.txt
```

Then following could provide you path name for files using parameter expansion.

```
echo ${A%/*}/
a/b/c/
```

Comment: With the trailing `/` character: `echo ${A%/*}/`

Comment: @JNevill, thank you sir have added / now into solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo a/b/c/d.txt | awk -F/ '{$NF=""}1' OFS=/
a/b/c/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with parameter expansion like in @RavinderSingh13's very good answer or `dirname` as @aragaer suggests, but if you are gung-ho about an awk solution, you could do something like:

```
echo "a/b/c/d.txt" | awk -F"/" '{ for (f=1;f<NF;f++){printf "%s/", $f}; printf "\n"}'
```

But that's horrible overkill when you can just `echo $(dirname "a/b/c/d.txt")/`

Comment: Thanks Jnevil..the echo one fits my requirement :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***sed*** approach:

```
echo "a/b/c/d.txt" | sed 's~/[^/]*$~/~'
a/b/c/
```